# Are arrays stored in reverse order in C/C++?

Tags: c++, c, arrays, assembly, nasm

I wanted to create a 4 elements array in Assembly:

```
; Create an array of 4 elements
push BYTE 'a'
push BYTE 'b'
push BYTE 'c'
push BYTE 'd'
```

And it came to my mind that arrays are stored in C/C++ in reverse order (first element has the lowest memory address and last element has the highest memory address), so to make sure my assumption is correct, I did the following test:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char arr[4] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'};

    printf("Address: %d Value: %c\n", arr + 0, *(arr + 0));
    printf("Address: %d Value: %c\n", arr + 1, *(arr + 1));
    printf("Address: %d Value: %c\n", arr + 2, *(arr + 2));
    printf("Address: %d Value: %c\n", arr + 3, *(arr + 3));

    return 0;
}
```

And the output was as expected:

```
Address: 3603656 Value: a
Address: 3603657 Value: b
Address: 3603658 Value: c
Address: 3603659 Value: d
```

So does this means that I should create the array in Assembly like this:

```
; Create an array of 4 elements
push BYTE 'd'
push BYTE 'c'
push BYTE 'b'
push BYTE 'a'
```

And assume that the first element of it is the address of 'a'. Or there is no problem in doing it like before and instead of incrementing by 1 to get to the next element I just decrement by 1?

---

**Edit:
I meant in reverse order as relative to the stack (which grows downwards).**

Comment: C is transformed into assembly so why you change the order of the insertion into the array? if in in you add a first to the array in Assembly you should keep the same order

Comment: Array storage order is a different matter then stack growth direction. An array is not created by pushing bytes to stack in assembly language. 
Can you rephrase your question?

Comment: I don't see how having the first element at the lowest address would be considered "reversed". You just seem to be mixing up the concept of arrays with the stack.

Comment: @Michael So I should initialize an array in Assembly like in the last example and have the address of the first element be the address of 'a'?

Comment: @John Why do you initialize an array using PUSH instruction?

Comment: @John You could do it either way around. As long as the pointer arithmetic works, what does it matter? However, you're not creating an array in the same way that a compiler would do it if you declared an array in your program.

Comment: @Joseph Mansfield You are right. I was just trying to follow the standard way of doing it.

Comment: @John: If you want to use `PUSH`, then yes, you'd have to push the elements in the order last-to-first.

Answer (score 0):

You are not creating array here. PUSH and POP is performed for stack and the universal rule for stack is: *Last in First out*.

If you want to create array, then you can simply use a series `mov` command:

```
mov <mem>,<const>  // x86 instruction
```

or use data definition directives

```
Array DW 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'
```

Comment: Well, actually I am creating and initializing the array at the same time. I mean how should I create an array in Assembly: sub esp, 4?

Comment: @John Yes. And then you can initialize it using MOV instruction.

Comment: @ILoveCoding Thanks. I thought (based on an answer from a previous question that PUSH is used to initialize it).

Comment: Methinks the OP is trying to initialize a stack-homed array via four `push` instructions rather than a `sub esp` and `mov` instructions.

Comment: `PUSH imm8` might be more compact (lead to smaller code) than a series of `MOV`s, if that matters. Even more compact (expect for really short arrays) would probably be to have a copy of the array data somewhere (i.e.  `foo: db 1,2,3,4,...`) and use a `rep movs` to copy the data to the stack.

Comment: @John `PUSH` is also correct as long as the order is consistent.

Comment: or push a single appropriately configured 32bit constant and be done with it.

Comment: @John To clarify this answer: the data to initialise the array with is usually stored in the text section of your binary. When the array needs to be created on the stack, the stack pointer is moved the appropriate number of bytes to fit the entire array and then the data is copied from the text section.

Comment: Also... beware the Nasm syntax `push byte 'a'`. The operand is stored as a byte, but a single byte is not stored on the stack (no such instruction!).

Comment: @Frank Kotler What do you mean "a single byte is not stored on the stack"? Do you mean I should make sure that the stack is aligned to a 4 bytes boundary?

Comment: @John: Quoting from [Intel's manual](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html): _"The D flag in the current code-segment descriptor determines the default operand size; it may be overridden by instruction prefixes (66H or REX.W). The operand size (16, 32, or 64 bits) determines the amount by which the stack pointer is decremented (2, 4 or 8). If the source operand is an immediate and its size is less than the operand size, a sign-extended value is pushed on the stack."_

Comment: @John As Micheal's answer explains, the "byte" is sign extended to four bytes (or whatever your stack size is). That's what gets pushed on the stack. The single byte 'a' is stored in the code, but sign extended before it is pushed. The `push byte ...` syntax has been known to confuse beginners. I don't know "how new" you are...

Comment: @Frank Kotler I am very new. "The single byte 'a' is stored in the code" Do you mean by that that the 'a' is stored in the text section as just 1 byte, but when the actual instruction is executed this 1 byte 'a' is converted to 4 bytes 'a'? And so 4 bytes will actually be pushed on the stack? And is this a NASM thing or a general rule in Assembly?

Comment: @Frank Kotler If I understand this correctly, this means I can't really push 1 byte into the stack. But can I mov a byte into the stack?

Comment: Right on all counts. It's an 80x86 thing, but the way we "say it" is a Nasm thing. "Old Nasm" - 0.98 and before -  chose the "long form" (the 'a' stored as 'a', 0, 0, 0) unless you said `push byte ...`. Nasm smartened up and will give the "short form" if possible. We no longer need to say `push byte ...`, and probably shouldn't - just because it "looks like" it's doing something it isn't.